# Approximating using normal

Tags: statistics

Assume all $X_i$'s are independent and follow the same distribution with mean $u$ and variance $v$. If there are $n$ $x_i$'s, where $n$ is large, the distribution of $$Y= X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n = nX$$ is approx. normal. The mean of the distribution of $Y$ will be $n\cdot u$ and $\mathrm{var}=n\cdot v$.

What confuses me is that since $\operatorname{var}(nx)=n^2\cdot\operatorname{var}(x)$ why don't we follow this rule in this approximation case and instead only multiply it by $n$?

Comment: let's say the distribution is the average of all these Xi's. then I see people divide the Xi's by n and divide the variance by n^2. which further confuses me since that is an approximate normal distribution as well.

Comment: If $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ then $\mathsf{Var}S_n=n\mathsf{Var}X_1$ as shown in my answer. Then $\mathsf{Var}(S_n/n)=(\mathsf{Var}S_n)/n^2=(n\mathsf{Var}X_1)/n^2=(\mathsf{Var}X_n)/n$. Here $S_n/n$ is the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(X_1+\cdots +X_n) = {} & \operatorname{var}(X_1)+\cdots + \operatorname{var} (X_n) \\
& \text{if } X_1,\ldots,X_n \text{ are independent,} \\[10pt]
= {} & n\operatorname{var}(X_1) \\
& \text{if all of the variances are equal.} \\[10pt]
\operatorname{var}(X_1+\cdots+X_1) = {} & \operatorname{var}(nX_1) \\[10pt]
= {} & n^2 \operatorname{var}(X_1). \\
& \text{In this cases } X_1,\ldots, X_n \text{ are not only} \\
& \text{not independent, but are all the same.}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

We do **not** have something like $X_1+\dots+X_n=nX$ (with $X$ as random variable that has the same distribution as the $X_i$) as you seem to suggest.

LHS is summation of *independent* random variables.

Then $$\operatorname{\mathsf{Var}}(X_1+\cdots+X_n)=\operatorname{\mathsf{Var}}X_1+\cdots+\operatorname{\mathsf{Var}} X_n = n\operatorname{\mathsf{Var}}X_1$$

The first equality on base of the fact that the $X_i$ independent.

The second equality on base of the fact that the $X_i$ have equal distribution, hence have equal variance.

RHS can be looked at as summation of random variable that are *dependent* in optima forma: $X_1=\cdots=X_n=X$.

Then $$\operatorname{\mathsf{Var}}(X_1+\cdots+X_n)=\operatorname{\mathsf{Var}}(nX_1) = n^2\operatorname{\mathsf{Var}}X_1$$

Comment: We do not have something like X1+⋯+Xn=nX (with X as random variable that has the same distribution as the Xi) as you seem to suggest.
this might be a stupid question but i ask only because i want to understand why,so why don't we have that?

Comment: if X1 to Xn all follow the same distribution with the same mean and standard deviation are they not equal to each other so we could say their sum is nX?

Comment: By stating that $X_1+\cdots+ X_n=nX$ we actually state that $X=(X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n$. But there is no reason to think that this $X$ has the same distribution as $X_1$. If $X,Y$ have the same **distribution** then this does not imply that $X=Y$. Throw a coin twice and let $X$ stand for the first outcome and $Y$ for the second. Then $X,Y$ have equal distribution, but the outcomes $X,Y$ can differ.

Comment: ok that was perfectly explained! thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're a little confused here; $nX_1$ has variance $n^2\operatorname{Var}X_1$, but $\sum_i X_i$ has variance $n\operatorname{Var}X_1$. Why? Because the covariance $\operatorname{Cov}(X,\,Y)=\overline{(X-\overline{X})(Y-\overline{Y})}$ is linear in each argument, and $\operatorname{Var}Y=\operatorname{Cov}(Y,\,Y)$. So $$\operatorname{Var} nX_1 = \operatorname{Cov}(nX_1,\,nX_1)=n^2 \operatorname{Cov}(X_1,\,X_1)=n^2\operatorname{Var} X_1,$$while if the $X_i$ are pairwise uncorrelated we have $$\operatorname{Var} \sum_i X_1=\operatorname{Cov} (\sum_i X_1,\,\sum_j X_j)=\sum_i\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,\,X_i)=\sum_i\operatorname{Var}X_i=n\operatorname{Var}X_1.$$

Comment: that does sort of help but let's say u sum up all the x's and find the distribution of their average. mean stays the same because first u multiplied by n and are now dividing by n. variance changes however because you're first multiplying by n to get the variance of their sum but then dividing by n^2 to get the variance of their average. why?

Comment: @SyedBukhari $\operatorname{Cov}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_i X_i,\,\frac{1}{n}\sum_j X_j)=\frac{1}{n^2}\times n\operatorname{Var}X_1=\frac{1}{n}\operatorname{Var}X_1$.

Comment: like when you're summing indep. variables up u need only multiply by n for the variance. then u call this new variable y. now the var of y/n = average will be vary/n^2? am i getting the logic correct? how so if that is the case?

Comment: @SyedBukhari It might be easier to think of it as a special case of the variables being dependent, viz. $\operatorname{Cov}(\sum_i a_i X_i,\,\sum_j a_j X_j)=\sum_{ij}a_i a_j \operatorname{Cov}(X_i,\,X_j)$. But in your problem, the $i\ne j$ terms vanish.

Comment: alright thank you!